# how to select a tab on a web page using web scraping by vba excel

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

i am trying to get data from this website https://worldwide.espacenet.com/patent/search/family/040428971/publication/EP2429240A1?q=pn%3DEP2429240A1 the link opens the home page, but i want to go to description page.

i am not able to select and click the tab elements.

The inspect element shows following dom

```
<li tabindex="0" class="prod-jss21 prod-jss24 prod-jss26 tabs__list__item--mlNCRXql" 
  role="tab" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false" 
  data-qa="descriptionTab_resultDescription">
  <span class="prod-jss25">Description</span></li>
  <span class="prod-jss25">Description</span>
```

I have written following code so far

```
Sub espacenet()

    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://worldwide.espacenet.com/patent/search/family/051267404/publication/US8805587B1?q=pn%3DUS8805587B1"
    
    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop
    
    Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
    
    Debug.Print (HTMLDoc.body.innerText)
    
    '------------------
    
    Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim RowNum As Long, ColNum As Integer
    
    
  
    
   Set HTMLTables = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("span")
    
    For Each HTMLTable In HTMLTables
            Debug.Print (HTMLTable.innerText)
    Next HTMLTable
    
    Set HTMLTable = HTMLDoc.getElementById("biblio-applicants-content")
       Debug.Print (HTMLTable.innerText)
    
     Set HTMLTable = HTMLDoc.getElementById("biblio-title-content")
       Debug.Print (HTMLTable.innerText)
        
      Set HTMLTable = HTMLDoc.getElementById("biblio-abstract-content")
       Debug.Print (HTMLTable.innerText)
       
    Set HTMLTable = HTMLDoc.getElementById("biblio-inventors-content")
    Debug.Print (HTMLTable.innerText)
    
     Set HTMLTable = HTMLDoc.getElementById("biblio-priority-numbers-content-0")
       Debug.Print (HTMLTable.innerText)
    
     Set HTMLTable = HTMLDoc.getElementById("biblio-Application-number-content")
       Debug.Print (HTMLTable.innerText)
       
       Set HTMLTable = HTMLDoc.getElementById("biblio-Publication-number-content")
       Debug.Print (HTMLTable.innerText)
  end sub
```

Comment: ie.document.querySelector("[data-qa='descriptionTab_resultDescription']").click css attribute=value selector. Slower than using class name (you can otherwise use a single class from the multi-value class) but not that you would notice. I think attribute selector, by experience, feels the more robust way to go in this case. It looks like template html.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, i am new to web scarping and i did try query selector in different form but didnt work. Can you give me the correct syntax of how to write ie.document.querySelector("[data-qa='descriptionTab_resultDescription']").click css attribute=value selector. Because when i use this sentence it gives error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page has a somewhat untypical function. If the browser is not at least 1,350 pixels wide, no tabs are displayed, but the navigation is carried out as a dropdown. So there is the possibility to control the dropdown or display the browser wide enough.

I have chosen the width in the macro. Firstly, this is very easy to implement and secondly, the dropdown may never be present at high screen resolutions. To prevent IE from sticking out of the screen to the right, I set its position to the far left.

Please read the comments in the VBA code too:

```
Sub espacenet()

  Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
  Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
  Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
  Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
  Dim HTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
  Dim HTMLCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
  Dim RowNum As Long, ColNum As Integer
  
  'The width must be at least 1.350 pixel to show the tab bar
  'Otherwise it's a dropdown, no tab bar
  IE.Width = 1350
  'Place the IE on the left side of the screen
  IE.Left = 0
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.navigate "https://worldwide.espacenet.com/patent/search/family/051267404/publication/US8805587B1?q=pn%3DUS8805587B1"
  Do While IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
  
  'Manual break to load dynamic content after
  'IE sends ready state complete
  'The last three values are hours, minutes, seconds
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5))
  
  Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
  
  Set HTMLTables = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("span")
  
  For Each HTMLTable In HTMLTables
    Debug.Print (HTMLTable.innerText)
  Next HTMLTable
  
  Set HTMLTable = HTMLDoc.getElementById("biblio-applicants-content")
  Debug.Print (HTMLTable.innerText)
  
  Set HTMLTable = HTMLDoc.getElementById("biblio-title-content")
  Debug.Print (HTMLTable.innerText)
  
  Set HTMLTable = HTMLDoc.getElementById("biblio-abstract-content")
  Debug.Print (HTMLTable.innerText)
  
  Set HTMLTable = HTMLDoc.getElementById("biblio-inventors-content")
  Debug.Print (HTMLTable.innerText)
  
  Set HTMLTable = HTMLDoc.getElementById("biblio-priority-numbers-content-0")
  Debug.Print (HTMLTable.innerText)
  
  Set HTMLTable = HTMLDoc.getElementById("biblio-Application-number-content")
  Debug.Print (HTMLTable.innerText)
  
  Set HTMLTable = HTMLDoc.getElementById("biblio-Publication-number-content")
  Debug.Print (HTMLTable.innerText)
  
  'The query selector from QHaars comment
  HTMLDoc.querySelector("[data-qa='descriptionTab_resultDescription']").Click
  
  'After a "click" you need another short break to do the things after the click
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3))
  
  'Here more of your code
End Sub
```